# Clojure Remove item from Vector at a Specified Location

Tags: vector, clojure

Is there a way to remove an item from a vector based on index as of now i am using subvec to split the vector and recreate it again. I am looking for the reverse of assoc for vectors?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`subvec` is probably the best way.  The Clojure docs say `subvec` is "*O(1) and very fast, as the resulting vector shares structure with the original and no trimming is done*".  The alternative would be walking the vector and building a new one while skipping certain elements, which would be slower.

Removing elements from the middle of a vector isn't something vectors are necessarily good at.  If you have to do this often, consider using a hash-map so you can use `dissoc`.

See:

- [subvec](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subvec) at `clojuredocs.org`
- [subvec](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/subvec) at `clojure.github.io`, where the official website points to.

Answer (score 33):

```
(defn vec-remove
  "remove elem in coll"
  [pos coll]
  (into (subvec coll 0 pos) (subvec coll (inc pos))))
```

Comment: This has better performance than all the other suggestions except the mapv selecting indices you want. But I think this is simpler and performance as I benchmarked it was only about a 2 percent slower.

Answer (score 18):

```
user=> (def a [1 2 3 4 5])
user=> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (vec (concat (take 2 a) (drop 3 a)))))
"Elapsed time: 1185.539413 msecs"
user=> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (vec (concat (subvec a 0 2) (subvec a 3 5)))))
"Elapsed time: 760.072048 msecs"
```

Yup - subvec is fastest

Answer (score 9):

The vector library [`clojure.core.rrb-vector`](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) provides logarithmic time concatenation and slicing. Assuming you need persistence, and considering what you're asking for, a logarithmic time solution is as fast as theoretically possible. In particular, it is much faster than any solution using clojure's native `subvec`, as the `concat` step puts any such solution into linear time.

```
(require '[clojure.core.rrb-vector :as fv])
(let [s (vec [0 1 2 3 4])]
  (fv/catvec (fv/subvec s 0 2) (fv/subvec s 3 5)))
; => [0 1 3 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution iv found to be nice:

```
(defn index-exclude [r ex] 
   "Take all indices execpted ex" 
    (filter #(not (ex %)) (range r))) 


(defn dissoc-idx [v & ds]
   (map v (index-exclude (count v) (into #{} ds))))

(dissoc-idx [1 2 3] 1 2)


'(1)
```

Comment: For removing a single item this is slower than using subvec, but for removing multiple indexes this is pretty nice.

Answer (score 4):

`subvec` is fast ; combined with transients it gives even better results.

Using criterium to benchmark:

```
user=> (def len 5)
user=> (def v (vec (range 0 5))
user=> (def i (quot len 2))
user=> (def j (inc i))

; using take/drop
user=> (bench
         (vec (concat (take i v) (drop j v))))
;              Execution time mean : 817,618757 ns
;     Execution time std-deviation : 9,371922 ns

; using subvec
user=> (bench
         (vec (concat (subvec v 0 i) (subvec v j len))))
;              Execution time mean : 604,501041 ns
;     Execution time std-deviation : 8,163552 ns

; using subvec and transients
user=> (bench
         (persistent!
          (reduce conj! (transient (vec (subvec v 0 i))) (subvec v j len))))
;              Execution time mean : 307,819500 ns
;     Execution time std-deviation : 4,359432 ns
```

The speedup is even greater at greater lengths ; the same bench with a `len` equal to `10000` gives means: `1,368250 ms`, `953,565863 µs`, `314,387437 µs`.

Comment: What clojure version did you use for the subvec w/ transients version? Going back 4ish years now, there's been an [open bug](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-787) for subvec being incompatible with transient, because `APersistentVector$SubVector does not implement IEditableCollection`. I assume that's why the example wraps the subvec call in `(vec (subvec ...))` though in my tests with clojure 1.7, `vec` in that case will still return a `clojure.lang.APersistentVector$SubVector`, presumably as an optimization since, but I haven't dug into the clojure source for that.

Comment: 1.6.0 I think. It was released a few months before this answer was written.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update for Clojure 1.8? As @RyanWilson mentioned, your transient example doesn't work with 1.8.

Comment: Replacing `vec` in your last example with `into []` works with Clojure 1.8 but that absolutely kills the performance :(. The fastest I can get is `(into (subvec v 0 i) (subvec v j))`, which is about 15% faster than your `using subvec` middle version on my computer…

Answer (score 3):

It may be faster to get the indexes you want.

```clj
(def a [1 2 3 4 5])

(def indexes [0 1 3 4])

(time (dotimes [n 100000] (vec (concat (subvec a 0 2) (subvec a 3 5)))))
"Elapsed time: 69.401787 msecs"

(time (dotimes [n 100000] (mapv #(a %) indexes)))
"Elapsed time: 28.18766 msecs"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility which ought to work with any sequence and not bomb if the index was out of range...

```
(defn drop-index [col idx]
  (filter identity (map-indexed #(if (not= %1 idx) %2) col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest but maybe the most idiomatic?

```
(defn remove-n [n coll]
  (let [indexed (map-indexed vector coll)
        cleaned (remove #(= n (first %)) indexed)]
    (map second cleaned)))
```