# How to drop the nth item in a collection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How can I drop the nth item in a collection? I want to do something like this:

```
(def coll [:apple :banana :orange])

(drop-nth 0 coll)  ;=> [:banana :orange]
(drop-nth 1 coll)  ;=> [:apple :orange]
(drop-nth 2 coll)  ;=> [:apple :banana]
```

Is there a better way of doing this than what I've come up with so far?

```
(defn drop-nth [n coll]
  (concat (take n coll) (nthrest coll (inc n))))
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using [`keep-indexed`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keep-indexed)?

```
(defn drop-nth [n coll]
   (keep-indexed #(if (not= %1 n) %2) coll))
```

This is a generic solution that works with every sequence. If you want to stick with vectors, you could use `subvec` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location).

Comment: This is a perfect answer to the question I asked. Better yet, you and others have pointed me to the question I should have asked, given that vectors are what I'm using anyway. :)

Comment: To remove every n-th element from the list, just substitute the condition with this `(not= (mod %1 n) 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
(defn drop-nth [n coll]
  (concat 
    (take n coll)
    (drop (inc n) coll)))
```

Comment: That works, but is pretty much the same as mine, right? Does it have any benefits over what I originally did?

Comment: Nearly identical. I think drop is lazy and nthrest isn't.

Comment: It looks like you're right about `nthrest` not being lazy, at least if [this comment](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/nthrest#comment_154) in the Clojure docs is accurate. I can't actually tell myself by [looking at the source](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/nthrest#source) for `nthrest`.