# Why isn't dissoc implemented for vectors in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I know that clojure's `clojure.lang.IPersistentVector` implements `assoc`, as in `(assoc [0 1 2 3] 0 -1) ; => [-1 1 2 3]`. I have also heard (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location) answer) that clojure's vector doesn't implement `dissoc`, as in `(dissoc [0 1 2 3] 0) ; => [1 2 3]`. If this functionality is so easily reproducible using `subvec`, is there any real reason why it shouldn't be implemented in `clojure.lang`, `clojure.core`, or even contrib? If not, is there any reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dissoc doesn't make much sense for vectors for two reasons:

1. The meaning of `dissoc` is "remove a key". You can't remove a key from a vector without causing other side effects (e.g. moving all future values)
2. `dissoc` would perform relatively badly on vectors if it had to move all subsequent keys - roughly O(n) with quite a lot of GC. Clojure core generally avoids implementing operations that aren't efficient / don't make sense for a particular data structure.

Basically, if you find yourself wanting to do `dissoc` on a vector, you are probably using the wrong data structure. A persistent hashmap or set is probably a better choice.

If you want a data structure which works as a vector but supports cutting out and inserting elements or subsequences efficiently, then it is worth checking out RRB trees: https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector

Comment: Everything you say is correct. BUT all of your points also argue against having assoc work with vectors, ya? If you add a key at a certain position, you have to move all subsequent values? I think OP asks a good question - why does Clojure do assoc but not dissoc - if one is done, it seems to me the other should as well? Unless I'm misunderstanding something about the performance of assoc, which is entirely possible.

Comment: `assoc` is fine for vectors since it replaces the value at a given position - it doesn't affect the values at other positions.

Comment: @RyanTate `assoc` doesn't *insert* into an array (e.g., the value shifting), it *replaces* the value at the "key" (index). You cannot change the *length* of an array w/ `assoc`, e.g., if you `assoc` past the end you get an OoB exception.

Comment: @DaveNewton you can use `assoc` to append to a vector, provided you pass the index of the last element plus one as the index argument.