# Removing the nth element of a vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to do a really basic problem in clojure and having some trouble wrapping my head around how vectors/lists work.

First off when I am defining the arguments of a function that has a vector as an argument, how do you represent that as an argument.

Would you just have it as a single variable say

```
(defn example [avector] (This is where the function goes) )
```

Or do you have to list each element of a vector or list beforehand?

```
(defn example [vectorpart1 vectorpart2 vectorpart3 vectorpart4 ] (This is where the function goes) )
```

Also, in terms of vectors and lists, does anyone know of commands that allow you to figure out the length of a vector or get the first/last/or nth element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure Remove item from Vector at a Specified Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location)

Comment: The question title seems to be at odds with the subsequent text.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the element at index `n` from vector `v`:

```
(defn remove-indexed [v n]
  (into (subvec v 0 n) (subvec v (inc n))))
```

For example,

```
(remove-indexed (vec (range 10)) 5)
;[0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]
```

Lots can go wrong:

1. `v` might not be a vector.
2. `n` might not be a whole number.
3. `n` might be out of range for `v` (we require `(contains? v n)`.

Clojure detects all these errors at run time. A statically typed language would detect 1 and 2 but not 3 at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example defines a function that takes a single argument, regardless of type. If you pass a vector then that argument will be set to a vector.

```
(example [1 2 3 4]) ;; (= avector [1 2 3 4])
```

Your second example defines a function which takes four arguments. You need to pass four separate values for calls to this function to be valid.

```
(example [1] [2] [3] [4])
;; (= vectorpart1 [1])
;; (= vectorpart2 [2])
;; (= vectorpart3 [3])
;; (= vectorpart4 [4])
```

It sounds like you might be thinking about the destructuring syntax, which allows you to destructure values directly from an argument vector.

```
(defn example [[a b c d]]
  ())
```

The literal vector syntax in the argument definition describes a mapping between the items in the first argument and symbols available in the function scope.

```
(example [1 2 3 4])
;; (= a 1)
;; (= b 2)
;; (= c 3)
;; (= d 4)
```

The other function that also sits in this space is `apply`. Apply takes a list or vector of arguments and calls a function with them in-place.

```
(defn example [a b c]
  (assert (= a 1))
  (assert (= b 2))
  (assert (= c 3)))
```

If we call this function with one vector, you'll get an arity exception.

```
(example [1 2 3])
;; ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed ...
```

Instead we can use `apply` to pass the vector as arguments.

```
(apply example [1 2 3])
;; no errors!
```

You'll find all the methods you need to work with vectors in the Clojure docs.

If you want to remove a specific element, simply take the elements before it and the elements after it, then join them together.

```
(def v [1 2 3])
(concat (subvec v 0 1) (subvec v 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your first example is correct.  You don't want to have to name every piece of your vector because you will commonly work with vectors of indeterminate length.  If you want to do something with that vector where you need its parts to be assigned, you can do so by [destructuring](http://blog.brunobonacci.com/2014/11/16/clojure-complete-guide-to-destructuring/).

The slightly longer answer is that the list of parameters sent into any clojure defn *already is a vector*.  Notice that the parameter list uses `[]` to wrap its list of args.  This is because in Clojure code and data are the same thing.  From [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/07/23/homoiconicity-clojure-macros/)...

> Lisps are homoiconic, meaning code written in the language is encoded as data structures that the language has tools to manipulate.

This might be more than you're looking for but it's an important related concept.

Here'a a quick example to get you going...  Pass a vector (of strings in this case) to a functions and it returns the vector.  If you `map` over it however, it passes the contents of the vector to the function in succession.

```
user=> (def params ["bar" "baz"])
#'user/params
user=> (defn foo [params] (println params))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo params)
[bar baz]
nil
user=> (map foo params)
bar
baz
(nil nil)
```

Additionally, look at the [Clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) to find more about things you can do with vectors (and everything else in Clojure).

Comment: Well the problem in question is I'm trying to remove the second element of a vector. So, say the function takes in a vector that contains [0,1,2,3]. Then I need it to return the same vector, but with the element removed so I'd get [0,1,3]

Comment: That question already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location

Comment: 1. Remember that it's zero-indexed.  2.  You probably want this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18319708/3662110

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. The only thing I need to figure out to do is figure out how to iterate over a vector For example if I have a vector of (1 2 3 4) and I wanted to add each element up. I have to figure out how to remove the 1 then the 2 and the 3 and then the 4. I also need to figure out how to remove the last element of a vector when I don't know how large the vector is and how to figure out how large a vector is in terms of how many elements it has.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of your initial question.  Comments are not a place to ask for more help.  If you have more questions you should to create new questions.  Overall, it sounds like you need to spend some time in the REPL working these things out on your own.  I suggest that you accept @DanPrince's answer because it's thoughtful and thorough.