# get array values based on a collection of indices

Tags: vector, clojure

I'm looking for a generalization of the `nth` function.
There is a nice function in Julia and I'm having trouble finding an equivalent in Clojure:

> getindex(A, inds...) Returns a subset of array A as specified by inds,
>   where each ind may be an Int, a Range, or a Vector.

This is related to this question:
[Clojure Remove item from Vector at a Specified Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394991/clojure-remove-item-from-vector-at-a-specified-location)

Comment: Your description of `Julia`'s `getindex` does not correspond to [that on the language web-site](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/?highlight=getindex#Base.getindex).

Comment: @Thumbnail I copied it from an earlier version. It works the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map` already does what you want. `(map v indices)` works as intended because a vector can be treated as a function of its indices.

Comment: True for maps too - not just vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need:

```
(defn get-nths [xs ns]
  (for [n ns]
    (nth xs n)))
```

?

Examples for a vector, a range and one only:

```
(defn x []
  (vector
    (get-nths [:a :b :c :d :e] [2 4])
    (get-nths [:a :b :c :d :e] (range 3))
    (get-nths [:a :b :c :d :e] [0])))

(x)
;; => [(:c :e) (:a :b :c) (:a)]
```

Answer (score 2):

with vectors you could also use `select-keys`. in some cases it can be quite helpful:

```
user> (select-keys [:a :b :c :d] [0 1])
{0 :a, 1 :b}
```

Comment: I understand that this can be useful. It amazes me that type stability is not as cherished in Clojure as in other languages.